# Break from regex loop in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

In Perl regex, how can I break from /ge loop..?

Let's say the code is:

```
 s/\G(foo)(bar)(;|$)/{ break if $3 ne ';'; print "$1\n"; '' }/ge;
```

...`break` here doesn't work, but it should illustrate what I mean.

Comment: Won't the regex stop automatically when it doesn't match?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JeffB - I wrote probably wrong example - the idea is to be able to stop parsing before it stops automatically...

Comment: For some reasons, it's a big hurdle for Perl recently-non-newbies to get over the idea of doing everything in a single statement (usually inside a match or substitution operator). :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, I would write this as a `while` statement:

```
while( s/(foo)(bar)/$1/ ) {
    # my code to determine if I should stop
    if(something) {
        last;
    }
}
```

The caveat with this method is that your search/replace will start at the beginning each time, which may matter depending on your regex.

If you really wanted to do it in the regex, you could write a function that returns an unmodified string if you reached your end point, such as a count in this case:

```
my $count=0;

sub myfunc {
    my ($string, $a, $b) = @_;

    $count++;

    if($count > 3) {
        return $string;
    }

    return $a;
}

$mystring = "foobar  foobar, foobar + foobar and foobar";
$mystring =~ s/((foo)(bar))/myfunc($1,$2,$3)/ge;

# result: $mystring => "foo  foo, foo + foobar and foobar"
```

If I knew your specific case, I could probably provide a more helpful example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some experimental features to emulate a break statement, the Perl documentation for some of these features warn that they may change in future versions of Perl.

```
my $str = "abcdef";
my $stop = 0;
$str =~ s/(?(?{ $stop })(?!))(.)/ $stop = 1 if $1 ge "c"; "X" /ge;
print "$str\n";
```

This will print `XXXdef`.

A piece wise explanation:

- `(?(condition)yes-pattern)` if the pattern in in `condition` matches then match `yes-pattern`, otherwise don't match anything.
- `(?{ code })` execute `code`, inside a conditional if the code is true execute the `yes-pattern`
- `(?!)` will always fail to match, it's meaning is something like "Don't match nothing" and since 'nothing' can be matched at any point in a string it will fail.

So when `$stop` is true the pattern can never match, and when `$stop` is false it matches.